# Image URL not working, has site URL added

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a PHP script that fetches the latest image from a directory. The script seems to work and returns the following:

```
<img src="webcam3/FI9804W_00626E4E4229/snap/Schedule_20140923-105158.jpg" alt="Webbkamera 3">
```

The base_url looks like this:

```
$base_url = 'webcam3/FI9804W_00626E4E4229/snap';
```

However the link has the site URL appended to it, so the link reads

```
http://www.hlmfk.se/webbkameror/kameratest/webcam3/FI9804W_00626E4E4229/snap/Schedule_20140923-105158.jpg
```

...when the address should be www.hlmfk.se/webcam3/... How do I prevent the site URL being added to the image link? Thanks!

The script looks like this and is written in the theme functions.php:

```
$dir = 'snap';
$base_url = 'webcam3/FI9804W_00626E4E4229/snap';
$newest_mtime = 0;
$show_file = 'BROKEN';
if ($handle = opendir($base_url)) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..') && ($file != '.htaccess')) {
       $mtime = filemtime("$base_url/$file");
       if ($mtime > $newest_mtime) {
          $newest_mtime = $mtime;
          $show_file = "$base_url/$file";
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: add a slash at the beginning of source: `<img src="/webcam3/...`

Comment: No, that doesn´t work either, `<img src="../webcam/...` neither it just returns an empty value. Is this .htaccess related?

Comment: "However the link has the site URL appended to it", what do you mean? I think it's vice-versa. If you think it's something .htaccess related, it would be useful to show us your .htaccess

Comment: it doesn't look like it's a .htaccess related problem. If you use include the following code: `<img src="/webcam3/FI9804W_00626E4E4229/snap/Schedule_20140923-105158.jpg" alt="Webbkamera 3">`, what URL do you get for the image?

Comment: Then I get `<img src="" alt="Webbkamera 3">` .

Comment: this is quite weird. I tried to go to http://www.hlmfk.se/webbkameror/kameratest/, then with browser inspector just added the slash at the beginning of the source, and I can see the image for webcamera3. In your PHP code, try to change `$base_url` to `'/webcam3/FI9804W_00626E4E4229/snap'` and refresh

Comment: Done... and I get src="" again.

Comment: Add the slash to the `$show_file` variable `$show_file = "/$base_url/$file";`. If you add it in front of the `$base_url` it will try to read the file from your server root and fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the / in the begining of the link:

```
$show_file = "/$base_url/$file";
```

(i'm assuming that you use the $show_file as the variable to print the

After that, the addressing will be ABSOLUTE, followed right after your domain name.

So you will get this: `http://www.hlmfk.se/webcam3/FI9804W_00626E4E4229/snap/Schedule_20140923-105158.jpg#.VCFNfMHgKBw`
which is working, instead of this: `http://www.hlmfk.se/webbkameror/kameratest/webcam3/FI9804W_00626E4E4229/snap/Schedule_20140923-105158.jpg#.VCFOLMHgKBx` which is not working, as the html will look for the webcam3/... RELATIVE to its current directory, which is /webbkameror/kameratest/ !